# In Oracle DB how to avoid decompiling of objects dependent on a DBLink?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-design, dblink

There is a DBLink to a remote DB and a package `MY_PACKAGE` (in the local schema) indirectly depending on it through `MY_VIEW`.

When DBLink is not valid (for whatever reason, i.e. connection is lost or credentials are changed on the remote) then the package becomes invalid. But it would be great to have it working, because this package has other responsibilities aside from negotiating through this DBLink. And overall, I do not think it is a desirable situation to have the schema object validity depending on an unstable parts like network connection.

I found this situation in a legacy code (see `MY_PACKAGE.doSomething()`) and I am not sure even **whether this is a correct design**. Could you share your opinion on this?

What is the **proper approach to keep the package in a VALID state** even when some DBLinks are not available?

For example, would it be correct to use a dynamic cursor referencing `MY_VIEW`, which fails to open ONLY when DBLink is not OK (i.e. `MY_PACKAGE.doSomethingAgain()`). Of course maybe there is a more natural approach to this problem. I will be glad to hear all options that could be appropriate for safe usage of DBLinks in Oracle.

**Code:**

```
-- DBLink --------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE DATABASE LINK "MY_LINK"
CONNECT TO "MY_USER" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES ':1' USING 'WHATEVER';
------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Synonym -------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE SYNONYM "MY_SYNONYM" 
FOR "MY_REMOTE_SCHEMA"."MY_REMOTE_VIEW"@"MY_LINK";
------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- View ----------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "MY_VIEW" AS 
SELECT a,b,c FROM "MY_SYNONYM";

> Compiler Error    
>   ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MY_LINK
>  ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>  [Oracle][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][SQL Server]
>  Login failed for user 'MY_USER'. {28000,NativeErr = 18456}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

```
-- Package body --------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS
  
    PROCEDURE doSomething()
    IS
      i NUMBER := 0;
    BEGIN  
      FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM "MY_VIEW")
      LOOP
        i := i + 1;
      END LOOP;
    END;
  
    PROCEDURE doSomethingAgain()
    IS
      i NUMBER := 0;
      my_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN  

      OPEN my_cur FOR 'SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW';
      
      LOOP
        FETCH my_cur -- ...

        -- etc ...

        i := i + 1;
      END LOOP;
    END;
END MY_PACKAGE;

> Compiler Error
> 7/4   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> 7/35  PL/SQL: ORA-04063: view "MY_VIEW" has errors
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option you have is to keep database links alive and kicking, I presume.

---

Another option is to move procedures - that use those suspicious database links - **out** of that package and make them either standalone stored procedures so that if they become invalid, only *they* are invalid (and not the whole package), or - possibly - put those procedures (that share the same destiny) into a separate package.

---

Yet another option is to use dynamic SQL because Oracle doesn't care whether any objects involved are valid or not until you actually try to use them. Something like this:

```
SQL> create database link my_link
  2  connect to whoever
  3  identified by whatever
  4  using 'database_that_does_not_exist';

Database link created.

SQL> create or replace view my_view as
  2  select * from some_table@my_link;
select * from some_table@my_link
                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc as
  2    l_id number;
  3  begin
  4    select id into l_id
  5    from my_view;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE MY_PROC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But, with dynamic SQL:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc as
  2    l_id number;
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'select id from my_view' into l_id;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Looks OK, but not for long:

```
SQL> exec my_proc;
BEGIN my_proc; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.MY_PROC", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Yes, I know - not all code is simple enough to put it into dynamic SQL. Bigger it is, worse problems you have to maintain it, so that's just possibility I wouldn't really want to use.